# Is it possible to use named Tuple with generic type declaration?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, tuples

I know we can declared a named tuples like:

```
var name = (first:"Sponge", last:"Bob");
```

However, **I cannot figure out how to combined the named tuple with a generic type, such as Dictionary**.

I have tried the below variations, but no luck:

```
Dictionary<string, (string, string)> name = new Dictionary<string, (string, string)>();

// this assignment yields this message:
// The tuple element name 'value' is ignored because a different name or no name is specified by the 
// target type '(string, string)'.
// The tuple element name 'limitType' is ignored because a different name or no name is specified 
// by the target type '(string, string)'.
name["cast"] = (value:"Sponge", limitType:"Bob");  

// I tried putting the name in front and at the end of the type, but no luck
// Both statements below produce syntactic error:
Dictionary<string, (value:string, string)> name;
Dictionary<string, (string:value, string)> name;
```

Does anyone know if C# supports the scenario above?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a two options here. First one is to declare the [named tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) with custom item names at `Dictionary` declaration, like that

```cs
var name = new Dictionary<string, (string value, string limitType)>();
name["cast"] = ("Sponge", "Bob"); //or name["cast"] = (value: "Sponge", limitType: "Bob");
```

And access an items in the following way

```cs
var value = name["cast"].value;
```

Second one is to use an unnamed tuple with default item names (`Item1`, `Item2`, etc.)

```cs
var name = new Dictionary<string, (string, string)>();
name["cast"] = ("Sponge", "Bob");
```

[Language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) for tuples was added in C# 7, please ensure that you are using this language version, or install [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/) package, if something is missing

Comment: Thank Pavel...the only I didn't try was putting the name after the type...string value...give mes what I needed...Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

In this case what matters is the names in the declaration of the `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, (string First, string Last)> SomeDictionary
    = new Dictionary<string, (string, string)>();
```

Then you can use the names like this:

```
var value = SomeDictionary["SomeKey"];
var first = value.First;
var last = value.Last;
//var (first, last) = SomeDictionary["SomeKey"]; // alternative, Tuple deconstruction
```